# laravel cashier syncing stripe ground truth on downtime

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

If stripe sends a webhook while my system is down, I will not receive the missed customer updates.

The laravel cashier docs do not seem to cover this situation, nor can I find a method where you would sync stripe => laravel instead of laravel => stripe (syncStripeCustomerDetails)

Combing through the stripe docs it seems to me that if my system is down, it will not re-attempt and just fail it entirely instead of retrying, unlike when e.g. a code 500 is returned ([webhook retries](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#built-in-retries))

What is the proper way to handle this? is load balancing to always return a 500 when not available the only way?

Thanks!

Comment: Stripe will re-try the endpoint. It says so in the linked document itself `Stripe webhooks have built-in retry methods for 3xx, 4xx, or 5xx response status codes`. It will inform your email if it continues to fail. You can test this by doing a transaction when your webhook is simulated to give 5xx error and turning that off a little later.

Comment: What concerned me is what comes right after: `If Stripe doesn’t quickly receive a 2xx response status code for an event, we mark the event as failed and stop trying to send it to your endpoint.` if my server is down for example, no code will be sent at all, hence the load balancer idea to at least report back a 500 when the content server is down, but it feels like there must be another solution to this, e.g. a sync ground truth when the server does come back online

Comment: In my experience, unless you are planning to have a downtime of hours (I'm talking 8~12 hours), this wouldn't be a problem. Even then, you get an email notification. On top of that, you can check the events from the stripe console and resend it (or check the payload to manually apply it).

Comment: is there no programmatic way to have it resent when I come back online? I'd imagine resending the events manually would take a while depending on how many were missed? or is it a batched resend? thanks

Comment: Webhooks are a way to listen to events. So, you can use the API to read events periodically to and not do webhooks at all if needed. https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/list (it is much much easier to listen to the events you select though. Your webhook endpoint should be able to process past events as well - the ones that get retried when your system is back on line)

Comment: perfect "delivery_success" looks exactly what I'd need to filter by, thanks! not sure if I can give you credit on SO for this (given low reputation score), but if I can, feel free to e.g. post an answer summarizing it and I'll mark it as solved or upvote it etc